# Is it possible to fill a select element with javascript and submit the form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

In a view I need two select elements. One of them will serve just as a dropdownlist to pick one and only option. WHen I press "Add" button, the currently selected option will be added to the second select which will serve more as a list box. So you select from one and add to the other(copy-paste not cut-paste). Here's my model:

```
  public class MyModel{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Officers{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<int> Executors{get;set;}// This will hold a list of ID's of the selected officers    
  }
```

So again, I need to select one or more officers from Officers and add their IDs- which is an int- to Executors. For Officers I've managed to populate a dropdownlist like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlOfficers", Model.Officers, new { id = "ddlOfficers" })
```

If you notice, the name property has a different value than "Officers", this is because I don't want it to bind to any model property (but it wouldn't be a problem even if I'd let it be). My question is, how do I create an element for the Executors property considering what I want to do.

EDIT: If I create a select with the help of ListBox or ListBoxFor, it asks for a SelectList, but the list should be empty and it should be filled by user with javascript, so I don't know what to do about.

Comment: yes it is possible but what you tried?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it up